# Javascript new Card is not recognized

Tags: javascript

I load my page with 5 cards, which I can click and interact with. After clicking one of them it disappears and a new card appears. Only problem is I can't interact with the new one. I am new to JavaScript so it might be a basic mistake. This is also my first question so please tell me if you need something else to know in order to solve this problem.

```
function GenerateHandCards(amount){
    for(var tagCounter = 1; tagCounter <= amount; tagCounter++){
        var myHandCard = DrawCard();
        var CardImage = $("<img id = '"+myHandCard.rank+ "_"+myHandCard.suit+"'>");
        CardImage.attr("src","CardImages/" + myHandCard.rank + "_of_" +myHandCard.suit + ".png");
        CardImage.appendTo('.HandCards');
    }
}
```

The lines above draw a card out of my deck that

> generate an img tag and append it to my division.

Here is the click event. I am sorry I forgot to include it.

```
$(".HandCards img").click(function() {
    var card = (this.id);
    CompareCards(card);
    $(this).remove();
    NewFieldCard();
    AddNewHandCard();
})
```

And here are the lines of code of the last two functions in case you need them for better understanding.

```
function AddNewHandCard(){
GenerateHandCards(singleCard);
}

function NewFieldCard(){
$(".FieldCard img").remove();
GenerateFieldCard();
}
```

Comment: is the click event on the image or div with class HandCards?

Comment: Include the code where you listen to the click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this code in your page initialization:

```
$(".HandCards img").click(function() {
    // ...
});
```

That attaches event listeners directly to each of the `img` elements inside `.HandCards`, but only to the `img` elements that exist at the time you run this initialization code. When you create a new `img` it doesn't have an event listener.

Change the code to use event delegation:

```
$(".HandCards").on( "click", "img", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Now there is a single event listener on the `.HandCards` element that applies to all `img` elements inside it, even ones you add later. When you create a new `img`, that event listener will still work with it.